# Sprachlicher Vergleich

Tags: comparison

Ich würde gerne wissen, ob folgende, auf einer Webseite gefundene Aussagen, sprachlich korrekt sind:

- Viel günstiger (halber Preis wie XYZ)
- Viel schneller (doppelte Leistung wie XYZ)

Sprachlich ist das für mich nicht stimmig. Vielmehr hört es sich für mich an wie *halber Preis [genau] wie XYZ*. Richtig wäre für mich: *halb so teuer wie XYZ*.

Comment: Das ist falsches 'schlechtes Deutsch'. In richtigem 'schlechten Deutsch' spricht man von: *halber Preis als wie XYZ* - *doppelte Leistung als wie XYZ*

Comment: Sehe ich genau so, aber wie kann ich das belegen. Die Kollegen vom Marketing sind von der Richtigkeit überzeugt.

Comment: Ich denke das *wie* hat sich hier von einem Vergleich wie dem von dir genannten 'halb so teuer wie' eingeschlichen. Außerdem lieben wir Deutschen das *wie*, immerhin ist sind Dinge ja auch 'teurer wie' etwas anderes. Hier würde ich aber sagen, ist die Angabe 'halber Preis' nicht wirklich ein Vergleich. Es stellt vielmehr eine direkte Relation dar, also würde ich sagen: 'halber Preis von'. Klingt für mich aber auch nicht überragend (in einer Masterarbeit würde ich es meiden), aber für Marketing allemal OK.

Comment: _Halber Preis im Vergleich zu XYZ, doppelte Leistung gegenüber XYZ_?

Comment: Was ist denn mit XYZ gemeint: der Hersteller/Verkäufer, das Produkt, oder der Preis mit dem verglichen wird. Das hat einen Einfluss darauf, was richtig wäre

Answer (score 6):

Klassischer Fall des Genitivs. Je nach Geschlecht (w/s/m):

```
Viel günstiger (halber Preis der Butter)
Viel günstiger (halber Preis des Sofas)
Viel günstiger (halber Preis des Mercedis)

Viel schneller (doppelte Leistung der Butter)
Viel schneller (doppelte Leistung des Sofas)
Viel schneller (doppelte Leistung des Mercedes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Laut dem Kommentar von Em1 wäre statt „wie“ wohl „von“ korrekt, also bspw.:

> Halber Preis von 19,98 €

Da ist aber m. E. das „Preis“ etwas holprig, daher eher:

> Die Hälfte von 19,98 €

Oder noch einfacher:

> (nur) 9,99 €

Und um das Ganze noch werbewirksam zu machen:

> 9,99 € - Sie sparen im Vergleich zu XY 50%!

Comment: Ja, hloprig ist es. Streng genommen ist "halber Preis von" auch nicht besser. Denn 19,95 ist bereits der Preis. "Halber Preis von 19,95" klingt aber so, als wäre 19,95 ein Objekt, das einen Preis hat, und davon dann die Hälfte.

Comment: War nicht nach einem anderen Produkt XYZ gefragt?

Comment: @Takkat: Das wusste ich jetzt nicht.

Comment: Das `von` in `halber Preis von 19,98 EUR` ist mehrdeutig. Erstens kann es die Referenzgröße bezeichnen, die halbiert werden soll. Zweitens kann es auch einfach die Angabe der Größe sein: „Er fährt mit einer erhöhten Geschwindigkeit *von* 100 km/h.“ - „Es kostet den halben Preis *von* 19,98 EUR.“